# How to use Angular-Strap to create a modal with a controller?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-strap

I'm struggling to find the right way to use an Angular-Strap modal/aside with a controller.

Yes, the calling code could inject the `$scope`, making it available to the modal. But there are issues with that.

```
myModal = $modal({
scope: $scope,
template: 'template.html',
show: false,
backdrop: "static",
keyboard: false,
persist: true
```

});

This will pollute the calling controller with potentially modal-only methods and properties.

I usually use "controllerAs", and therefore don't even have a `$scope` to inject into the modal in the first place!

You could create a new `$scope` and then insert methods into that, but again, that would require injection of `$scope` into the parent controller. Bad bad bad.

If I use `ng-controller` inside the modal template, I can have my controller. But his gives me another problem: now I cannot inject data into the modal controller, and there is no way my calling code can know when the modal is closed and returning data from the modal also becomes a chore (involves a factory just to keep the parent and child controller data synchronized).

I'm really struggling how to make this the best way.

Any ideas?

Cheers

**Update**

This is how I do it for now:

In my template I make a directive that opens up the modal.
Example:

```
<my-modal
        on-update="ctrl.OnDialogUpdate">
</my-modal>
```

So basically the directive calls my modal and when the modal closes or wants to return with a result, it calls the method specified in the directive parameter.

This is how the directive could look:

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular.module('app').directive('myModal',myModal);

function myModal(){

    return {

        restrict: 'E',

        // The modal callback specified in the directive tag
        scope: {
            onUpdate: '&?'
        },

        replace: true,

        // This is the template for the directive, not the modal
        templateUrl: 'button.html',

        controllerAs: 'ctrl',

        bindToController: true,

        compile: function (element, attrs) {

            return function (scope, element, attrs) {

            };
        },


        /*@ngInject*/
        controller: function($scope, $log, $aside){

            var self = this;

            var myDialog = $aside({

                // Dialog template
                template: 'my-modal.template.html',
                show: false,
                animation: 'am-fade-and-slide-right',
                placement: 'right',
                backdrop: true,
                html: true,
                container: '',
                scope: $scope
            });


            // Opens modal
            self.ShowDialog = function(){
                myDialog.$promise.then(function() {
                    myDialog.show();
                })
            };


            // Expose Update() method to the dialog template
            $scope.Update = function(){

                if(angular.isFunction(self.onUpdate) ) {

                    self.onUpdate()();
                }

            }

        }
    }

}

})();
```

Comment: I've basically solved my issue. What I do is making a directive which opens the $modal. The directive has a controller, and also a $scope that is injected into the dialog.  I will try to add some code later..

Comment: I'm desperate to solve the same issue myself right now. I'd be extremely grateful if you could please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: It's very difficult to plunker a valid solution but I'll try to explain what I did (will update the question)

Comment: Hi Spock, I managed to come to a solution myself in the meantime, too. I will try to find a few minutes to post what I did as an answer also.

Comment: Hi Trevor, thanks.. it's a bit messy with Angular-Strap. I have been looking into https://github.com/btford/angular-modal     as well, is much more clean. There are also other very nice Angular modal projects out there...

Comment: Oh - I suggest you post your current solution as an answer (rather than appending to your question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the 'controller' option:

```
$scope.showModal = function() {
  $modal({
    title: 'My Title', 
    content: 'My Content', 
    show: true,
    controller: 'ModalCtrl'
  });
};
```

[Here's a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uDC1GSnJo5enoJ26Dsv4?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use:

```
var modal= $modal({
            templateUrl: '.../../xxx.modal.html',
            show: false,
            backdrop: 'static',
            controller: 'anyCtrl as vm'
        });
```

In this case your modal dialog will have the scope of the "anyCtrl" Controller. In the template you can just use vm.title or other properties which are defined in the controller.